# The basis of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}/\left \langle x^{2}+x+1 \right \rangle$ is $\left \{ [1], [x] \right \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that $A=\left \{ [1], [x] \right \}$  is a basis of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}/\left \langle x^{2}+x+1 \right \rangle$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

The first thing I did was see that the elements of the ring were $[0], [1] ,[x]$ and $[x+1]$. Then to show that it's a basis, it must be proved that the set A span the ring and that the elements of A are linearly independent.

To see that it span the ring, I must see that it generates the elements $[0]$ and $[x + 1]$, so $[x + 1] = 1\cdot [x] + 1 \cdot [1]$, but $[0] = 0 + p(x)$ , ($p (x) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$)

I don't know if I can say that $[0]=0\cdot [x]+p(x)\cdot [1]$, because $[1] = (1 + q (x))$ and thus $[0] = p (x) + p (x) q (x)$ which becomes a polynomial again

I appreciate any comments

Comment: You can always span zero, taking every coefficient in a linear combination to be zero. E.g. $[0] = 0*[1] + 0*[x]$.

Comment: Note that $[x^2]=[x]+[1]$, $[x^3]=[1], [x^4]=[x]$, etc.

Comment: Your title and the body of your question differ slightly, and there's a subtle error in the title; $\{[1], [x]\}$ is _a_ basis of $\mathbb{Z}_2/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$, but not the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something a bit more general is true. Take $k$ a field (such as $\mathbb{Z}_2$) and $$f = a_nX^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} \ldots + a_1 X + a_0 \in k[X]$$ with $a_n \neq 0$. Then $B = \{[1], [X], \ldots, [X]^{n-1}\}$ is a $k$-basis for $k[X]/(f)$ as a $k$-vector space.

To see this: pick $[g] \in K[X]/(f)$. Since $k$ is a field, we know that $k[X]$ has a division algorithm. Namely, there exist unique $q,r \in k[X]$ with $r = 0$ or $\deg r < n$ such that $g = qf + r$; and so $[g] = [qf]+[r] = [r]$. But since either $r = 0$ or $r$ has degree less than $n$, we have

$$
r = b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots + b_{n-1}X^{n-1}
$$

with $b_1, \ldots, b_{n-1} \in k$ (some or even all of these may be zero). Consequently,

$$
[g] = [r] = b_0[1] + b_1[X] + \cdots +b_{n-1}[X^{n-1}]
$$

and thus $B$ is a set of generators. Finally, to see that $B$ is linearly independent, suppose that

$$
0 = b_0[1] + b_1[X] + \cdots +b_{n-1}[X^{n-1}] = [b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots + b_{n-1}X^{n-1}]
$$

for some $b_i \in k$. This means that there exists $g$ such that

$$
b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots + b_{n-1}X^{n-1} = gf.
$$

But that's impossible unless $b_0 = \cdots = b_{n-1} = 0$ and $g = 0$, as otherwise the right hand side has degree $\deg gf \geq \deg f = n$.