# Let $F$ be a field. Prove that for every integer $n \geq 2$, there exist $p,q \in F$ such that $x^2 + x + 1$ divides $x^n + px + q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

How to start the proof? I only know when $n = 2$ the remainder is $(p-1)x+q-1$ but I'm not sure.
Thanks for help

Comment: Yeah, your calculation is ok for $n = 2$ as in that case $x^n+px+q$ is **equal** to $x^2 + x + 1$ when $p = q = 1$. And, as you claim, that is precisely the condition that forces the remainder to be zero.

Comment: But how to prove it when n ≥ 2?

Comment: This looks like a great question! Can you try to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Aw that is the exact question

Comment: It is a shame to remove the problem, since other people might benefit from your question @Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to prove *existence* of $p,q$. So let's make this as simple as possible.

$$x^n +x+1 = p(x)[x^2+x+1] + ax+b$$ for some $a,b \in F$ and some $p(x) \in F[x]$.  Do you see why this is. You don't need to know precisely what $a$ and $b$ are, just that $x^n +x+1$ can be written in this form for *some* $a,b \in F$.

1. If $a$ and $b$ are both 0 then we are done.
2. Otherwise, note the following: $$x^n +x+1 = p(x)[x^2+x+1] +(ax+b).$$ So subtracting $ax+b$ from both sides gives $$x^n+n+1 -(ax+b) = p(x)[x^2+x+1].$$ Thus $x^2+x+1$ divides $x^n +x +1 -(ax+b)$. So take $p =1-a$ and $q=1-b$.

Comment: $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$. I editted to clear that up

Comment: I gave one more hint, you should be able to finish from there.

Comment: Okay thank youu

Comment: I editted it one more time

Comment: I can't figure it out :(

Comment: well what step are you stuck at?

Comment: $x^n+x+1 = p(x)[x^2+x+1] +(ax+b)$. So subtract $ax+b$ from both sides and what do you get.

Comment: Yes, exactly, which is what you want. Do you see why this is

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: You're quite welcome @Sergio . Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In general $-p x - q$ should be the remainder for the division of $x^n$ by $x^2+x+1$.  But we can make this explicit:

If $n \equiv 0 \mod 3$ then $x^n -1$ works

If $n\equiv 1 \mod 3$ then $x^n - x$

If $n \equiv 2 \mod 3$ then $x^n + x + 1$

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $s,t$ are polynomials, then $t = qs+r$ with $r = 0$ or $\deg r < \deg s$. In particular there always exists $r$ with $r = 0$ or $\deg r < \deg s$ such that $t-r$ is divisible by $s$.

Here $t = x^n$ and $s = x^2+x+1$. The condition $\deg r < 2$ can be expressed by saying that $r = px+q$ for some $p,q \in F$. So, to sum up, there are always $p,q$ such that

$$
t-r = x^n-px-q
$$

is divisible by $s = x^2+x+1$ (you can replace $p$ and $q$ with $-p$ and $-q$ for this to fit the original question).

A concise way to say this is that $F[X]/(s)$ is always a $F$-vector space with basis $\{[1],[X],\ldots, [X]^{d-1}$} where $d = \deg s$ ([here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981445/362866) a proof), hence for any $t \in F[X]$ there exist $a_0,\ldots, a_{d-1}$ such that

$$
a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{d-1}x^{d-1} \equiv t\pmod{s}.
$$